# Rails attr_accessor and attr_writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*newbie alert*

I'm watching one of Ryan Bate's RailsCasts  on virtual attributes. He's adding tags to an article on a blogging platform. http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/videos/167-more-on-virtual-attributes.mp4

At one point he has working code

```
attr_accessor :tag_names
```

In this example, the tag names do not appear in the form if they validate, so he changes the name of the attribute, and adds a method so that the tag names persist if there's a validation error on a different field

```
attr_writer :tag_names



def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

My question is, can you please explain the significance of changing it from `attr_accessor` to `attr_writer` in combination with the method he added?  **Why did he need to change the attribute name when he added that method?**

(note, i have read documentation about attr_accessor and attr_writer, but it's still not clicking enough so I'm not getting why he's making this change when he creates that method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`attr_accessor: :tag_names` creates these two methods:

```
def tag_names
  @tag_names 
end
```

and

```
def tag_names=(value)
  @tag_names=value
end
```

Because Ryan has his own `tag_names` ("reader") method he doesn't need to dynamically create it with `attr_accessor`. He needs only the ("writer") method which is created by `attr_writer`.

Comment: `attr_accessor :tag_names`